# cannot convert method group or convert array to list as its a method

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I get an error in the bellow code it says I cannot convert method group ListStudents to generic.list, if I try () at the end of ListStudents I get: cant convert array to list

All im trying to do is hardcode some users to an array and return them in my GET request is there a fix for this?

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "")]
    List<Student> GetStudentCollection();
}
[DataContract(Name="Student")]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
{
    public Student[] ListStudents()
    {
       List<Student> student = new List<Student>()
       {
           new Student { StudentID="bla", FirstName="bla", LastName="bla"},
           new Student { StudentID="bla1", FirstName="bla1", LastName="bla1"},
           new Student { StudentID="bla2", FirstName="bla2", LastName="bla2"}
       };
        return student.ToArray();
    }

    public List<Student> GetStudentCollection()
    {
        return ListStudents(); //error on this line, cant convert array to list
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `ToList` linq extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public Student[] ListStudents()
{
   List<Student> student = new List<Student>()
   {
       new Student { StudentID="bla", FirstName="bla", LastName="bla"},
       new Student { StudentID="bla1", FirstName="bla1", LastName="bla1"},
       new Student { StudentID="bla2", FirstName="bla2", LastName="bla2"}
   };
    return student.ToArray();
}

public List<Student> GetStudentCollection()
{
    return ListStudents().ToList(); //<-- this is the change you need
}
```

However, to **reduce the number of conversions** I would suggest changing the methods as follows:

```
public Student[] ListStudents()
{
   return GetStudentCollection().ToArray();
}

public IList<Student> GetStudentCollection()
{
   var students = new List<Student>()
   {
       new Student { StudentID="bla", FirstName="bla", LastName="bla"},
       new Student { StudentID="bla1", FirstName="bla1", LastName="bla1"},
       new Student { StudentID="bla2", FirstName="bla2", LastName="bla2"}
   };

   return students();
}
```

Comment: Not Valid in the given context

Comment: @Garrith, It should work, make sure you include the using statement, Updated answer to be more clear.

Comment: ahh I missed the using statement!!

Answer (score 2):

`ListStudents` is a method, not a property, so try this:

```
return ListStudents();
```

Also, change `ListStudents()` method to return a `List` like this:

```
    public List<Student> ListStudents()
    {
        List<Student> student = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student { StudentID="bla", FirstName="bla", LastName="bla"},
            new Student { StudentID="bla1", FirstName="bla1", LastName="bla1"},
            new Student { StudentID="bla2", FirstName="bla2", LastName="bla2"}
        };
        return student;
    }
```

Comment: cannot implicity convert array to list? If i try that

Comment: That's another error, your return type does not match declared type.

Comment: I.e., change `ListStudents()` to return a `List`.

Comment: It says liststudents is a method which is not valid in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason for using an array just return the list as is. Why spend the CPU to convert down to an array, then back up to a List:

```
public class RawDataService : IReceiveData
{
    public List<Student> ListStudents()
    {
       List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
       {
           new Student { StudentID="bla", FirstName="bla", LastName="bla"},
           new Student { StudentID="bla1", FirstName="bla1", LastName="bla1"},
           new Student { StudentID="bla2", FirstName="bla2", LastName="bla2"}
       };
        return students;
    }

    public List<Student> GetStudentCollection()
    {
        return ListStudents(); //error on this line, cant convert array to list
    }
```

But, if you must return the array, then change the line with the error to:

```
  using System.Linq;
  ...
  return ListStudents().ToList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030872/list-datamembers-into-listbox I just thought an array would be more wiser?

Comment: O btw Justin finaly figured out how to pass info back and forth now for a rest service in a console app!

Comment: @Garrith good. But, whether you are using a List or an Array shouldnt matter. In fact, in this case your final return type is a List...which is why it is unnecesary to downcast and then upcast...it is unnecessary CPU spent...If you do have any problems with types, just use the KnownTypeAttribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx